# Find and Replace for Complex String

Tags: shell, replace, sed

I have a input file containing a sentence like

```
typedef void * __builtin_va_list;
```

I want to replace this with

```
typedef void ** __builtin_va_list;
```

I tried using sed as follows

```
sed 's/void * __builtin_va_list/void ** __builtin_va_list/g' FILE.txt
```

But it is not working. I think it is due to involvement of *'s in expression. How can we handle this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this search/replace with captured groups and back-references:

```
sed -r 's/(void \*)( __builtin_va_list)/\1*\2/g' file
typedef void ** __builtin_va_list;
```

Also remember that `*` needs to be escaped since it is special regex meta character.

Comment: I think you're instructing  to replace single * with 2 *'s. Am I right?

Comment: Yes that is correct> I already have one `*` in first capturing group, that's why adding one more after `\1`

Comment: Capture groups may be a bit overkill for this simple case, but its good to know anyway. Simply escaping the `*` is enough: `sed 's/typedef void \*/&*/'`

Comment: @A.Danischewski: True but then it will match everything after `*` in input string. It might be okay for OP but there is a difference.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the stars:

```
sed 's/void \* __builtin_va_list/void \*\* __builtin_va_list/g' FILE.txt
```

Comment: No need to escape in the replacement.